# How to authenticate JWT Tokens with Passport.js generated for multiple roles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, passport.js

I've a use-case. My application has multiple users where not all users have the access to all the functionalities in the application. I have to restrict them from accessing the application. For that, I've been writing logic that works as the gateway.

I've created different `rules` which provides a different kind of authentication methods.

When a user log in to the application, will generate a JWT token upon successful login. That token will be authenticated using the rules given.

Here's my code.

**server.js**

```
global.app = new require("express")();
global.passport = require("passport");

require("./bin/kernal");
require('./bin/passport');
----Remaining Code----
```

**TokenAuth.js**

```
var passport = require("passport");
require("../../bin/passport");


module.exports= function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', function (error, user) {
        console.log(user);
        if (error) return next(error);
        if (!user) return res.status(401).json({"error":"Incorrect data", "status":401, "success":false});
        //req.user = user;
        next();

    })(req, res, next);
};
module.exports.UserAuth = function(req, res, next){ // Error Web Response
    passport.authenticate('user_rule', function (error, user) {

        if (error) return next(error);
        if (!user) return res.status(500).json({"message":"No User found", "status":500, "success":false});
        //req.user = user;
        next();

    })(req, res, next);
};
```

**Passport.js**

```
var passport = require("passport");

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('../app/middlewares/TokenAuth')

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

var options = {};

options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
options.secretOrKey = process.env.jwt_secret;

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(options, function (payload, done) {
    console.log(payload)
    User.findOne({_id: payload._id}, function (error, user) {

        if (error) return done(error, false);
        if (!user) return done(null, false);
        // req.auth_user = {"_id":user._id,"email":user.email,"name":user.name,"status":user.status}
        done(null, user);
    });
}));

passport.use('user_rule',    // UserAuth in TokenAuth.js has to use this functionality
    new JwtStrategy(options,async function (payload, done) {
        console.log(payload)
        let err, authUser,companyResource;
        [err,authUser] = await to(CompanyContacts.findById(payload._id).populate('company',
                                ["accountid","company_name","email","status"]).lean().exec());

        if (err) return done(err, false);
        if (!authUser) return done(null, false);
        let user= authUser;
        if(user.status==true && user.company.status==true){
            req.auth_user = {"_id":user._id,"email":user.email,"name":user.fullname,status:user.status,isPrimary:user.primarycontact};
            req.auth_company=user.company._id;
            req.isAdmin=false;
            req.auth_role=user.role;
            done(null, user);
        }else{
            return done(err, false);
        }
    })
);
```

**user_api.js**

```
router.get("/all/menus",TokenAuth,MenuController.getAllDropDowns);
router.post("/company/user/signin", TokenAuth.UserAuth, AuthController.customerlogin);
```

Here, when the `post` api get executed, only the user who gets authenticated has to get the access that api.

But the problem here is, whenever I use this authentication methods, I'm getting the error specified below.

```
{
    "error": "Incorrect data",
    "status": 401,
    "success": false
}
```

As per my knowledge, the data is not going into the `Passport.js` file to get authenticate.

Is this approach good, or do I need to make any changes in this code to make it work?